# Does the Server Key Exchange sign a hash or text

Tags: signature, tls, key-exchange

In TLS 1.2 when using ECDHE_RSA, the `ServerKeyExchange` message contains a signature over the server's ECDHE public parameters. My question is: Is the signature over a hash of the parameters or over a plain text of the parameters?

The specs does not clarify:

```
  struct {
      select (KeyExchangeAlgorithm) {
          case dh_anon:
              ServerDHParams params;
          case dhe_dss:
          case dhe_rsa:
              ServerDHParams params;
              digitally-signed struct {
                  opaque client_random[32];
                  opaque server_random[32];
                  ServerDHParams params;
              } signed_params;
          case rsa:
          case dh_dss:
          case dh_rsa:
              struct {} ;
             /* message is omitted for rsa, dh_dss, and dh_rsa */
          /* may be extended, e.g., for ECDH -- see [TLSECC] */
      };
  } ServerKeyExchange;

  params
     The server's key exchange parameters.

  signed_params
     For non-anonymous key exchanges, a signature over the server's
     key exchange parameters.
```

As you see, it says on the `signed_params`:

> a signature over the server's key exchange parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signature generation includes hashing. So there is no need to perform hashing separately. This is why the signature schemes that are used will always indicate the hash to be used - either directly or indirectly using parameters.

Without the hash the signature would be vulnerable to key-only existential forgery attacks. I don't see how that would influence the security of TLS, but TLS in general tries to use standardized primitives within the protocol

Note that TLS up to 1.2 contains rather a lot of legacy constructions that would be considered non-standard by now, TLS 1.3 tries to resolve this by using RSA-PSS and SHA-2 (in the 256, 384 and 512 bit versions) which is provably secure if RSA and SHA-2 are secure.

So yes, hashing is used, but only as part of signature generation.

Comment: First answer edited and posted using my Ultimate Hacking Keyboard :) I'm not sure if I will ever get used to it, but geeky it is...

Comment: Divide & Conquer it!

Answer (score 2):

As to the specs, note that [4.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.7) says

```
In RSA signing, the opaque vector contains the signature generated
using the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature scheme defined in [PKCS1]. ...
```

referencing (then-current) RFC3447 which unambiguously defines the whole signature process: hash, then encode, then pad, then the RSA modular exponentiation.

Note that TLS DSA and ECDSA signatures are just the standard notSchnorr(hash(M)) but TLS1.2 (protocol) RSA signatures are PKCS1v1_5 which is in brief

$$\operatorname{modexp}(n,d) (\operatorname{add01FF...00} (\operatorname{DERSEQ} (\operatorname{hash}(M)))))$$

while in TLS1.1 and earlier they were a variant of PKCS 'type 1' or even 'type 0' $$\operatorname{modexp}(n,d) (\operatorname{maybe\_add01FF...00} (\operatorname{SHA1concatMD5}(M)))$$ -- as noted in that same paragraph. And TLS1.3 changes to PSS instead.

Meta: Mathjax *somewhat* better, thanks SEJPM.

Comment: you may want to wrap your operators into `\operatorname{operatorname here}(arguments here)`

Comment: You can find a lot of formatting hints [here](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/1172). Just linking to PKCS#1 would do the trick as well though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: PKCS1 takes about a page in total to lay out each signature scheme in detail; I wanted to emphasize the differences by ignoring the parts not important here.